# Is it possible to record “sign in audit reports” in Azure AD Microsoft (Individual) Accounts even though the documentation states otherwise?

Tags: azure-active-directory

previously, I had provided the following information to my customer.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Azure-Active-Directory-sign-in-and-audit-reports-940d7b1b-4447-4024-b02c-e57c42121a96

“Events for the last 30 days are displayed in the list. The activity report includes the date and time that the user signed in, the application signed into, the user’s IP address, the user’s location when signing in, and the type of client device used to sign in. Events are logged for only work or school account sign-ins. Events aren’t logged when the user signs in using a Microsoft account.”

However, my customer has been able to confirm that Microsoft (Individual) Accounts do in fact record SOME audit report records (sign in audit records to be exact).  (He claims he knows that he knows for sure that the account he registered using OutlookJP did in fact record these reports. )

Also, my customer claims from experience that when inviting an Azure AD account / user from a different organization (Work Account), these reports were NOT recorded, which runs counter to what the documentation states

Is are there any other factors outside of the type of account used that would influence whether these signs in audit reports get recorded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my test , both microsoft account and account from a different organization will include in `Sign-ins` activity in new portal .Below is microsoft account sign in logs :
[image]

And below is records for the account from a different organization:
[image]

Sign-ins don’t appear immediately in the sign-ins activity log. It can take anywhere from 15 minutes to 2 hours to see the sign-in logs in the Azure portal.

You could click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-activity-sign-ins) for more details about sign-in activity reports in the Azure Active Directory portal

Comment: Thank you so much Nan Yu.  I will comb thru this to see if there is anything that applies to what my customer may have done incorrectly.

Thanks again

Comment: @PeterThurwachter , Sign-ins don’t appear immediately in the sign-ins activity log. It can take anywhere from 15 minutes to 2 hours to see the sign-in logs in the Azure portal.

Comment: Hello again Nan Yu.  I can't thank you enough for the help you have extended me.  Would you happen to know if any of the "Pre-requisites" listed in the document you provided me would also affect things outside of gaining access to sign-in reports?  I am especially interested in knowing if it can affect one's ability to reset a password.  

Would having Azure AD Premium license associated to a tenants' account allow for the tenant to reset their password?  

My customer says the reset button for those tenants he invited was greyed out and unclick able.   

Thank you in advance,
Peter

Comment: Glad to help you , if my reply helps, please consider mark the reply as answer which may help others who meet same problem . And in my opinion, the reset password button doesn't related to Azure AD Premium license . Only admin account could reset another user's account .

Comment: Thank you, for your response.  I upvoted your answer, but unfortunately, I do not have enough points to affect the answer publicly.

Comment: So seems you don't solve your question since you not mark as answer . what is the problem ? Does your customer continue not see the sign-ins activity log? Any problem, please feel free to let me know

Comment: Sorry Nan, this was my first time using Stackoverflow and I misunderstood what you were requesting of me.  If the green check mark appears by the reply, it is now marked as the answer correct?

Comment: @PeterThurwachter , yes , that's marked :) . Glad to help you that :)